# Posting data to endpoints

Tags: java, api

Here's the code I am trying to refactor. The same Http client is being used in each nested try with resource. I don't understand the rationale behind nesting client.execute() calls.

The code tries to Post data to an endpoint if resource is missing and retries to Post to a backup endpoint if earlier call fails

```
public void makeSeveralApiCalls() throws Exception {
  try (final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    try (final CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGetUri())){
      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
        // Resource not found, Post data to Microservice A
        try (final CloseableHttpResponse nestedResponse = client.execute(httpPostToMicroserviceA())) {
          if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201) {
            LOGGER.info("Success");
          } else {
            // Microservice A could not consume data, log error response
            final String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            LOGGER.debug("Error response: " + responseString);
            // Try to Post to Microservice B
            try (final CloseableHttpResponse subResponse = client.execute(httpPostToMicroserviceB())) {
              if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201) {
                LOGGER.info("Success");
              } else {
                // Is this exception propagated to the caller?
                throw new RuntimeException("Very bad unrecoverable state");
              }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a valid way to call multiple executes on the same HTTP client in a nested fashion. Is it better to separate out each `client.execute()` call?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Generally we don't answer `How to` questions because `How to` indicates that the code is not working as expected and we only review code that is working as expected. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The title of the question should also be about what the code does, and not what your concerns about the code are.

Comment: Are you the author and/or maintainer of this code? The following statement makes me wonder: “_I don't understand the rationale behind nesting client.execute() calls._” Per the site rules: [“_For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is._”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm not ready to believe `LOGGER.info("Success");` is the purpose of the *staggered* `client.execute()` calls I see: Please [don't present dumbed-down code for review here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should split up this method into smaller ones. The inline comment give you a perfect sign what should be extracted.

Also *try with resource" can handle more than one resource in a single statement.

```
public void makeSeveralApiCalls() throws Exception {
  try (final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
       final CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGetUri());
      ){
      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
        // Resource not found
        postDataToMicroserviceA(client, response);      
       }
    }
}

private void postDataToMicroserviceA(CloseableHttpClient client, CloseableHttpResponse response){
  try (final CloseableHttpResponse nestedResponse = client.execute(httpPostToMicroserviceA())) {
          if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201) {
            LOGGER.info("Success");
          } else {
            // Microservice A could not consume data, 
            logErrorResponse(client, response);           
          }
  }
}

private void logErrorResponse(CloseableHttpClient client, CloseableHttpResponse response)
            final String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            LOGGER.debug("Error response: " + responseString);
            // Try to Post to Microservice B
            try (final CloseableHttpResponse subResponse = client.execute(httpPostToMicroserviceB())) {
              if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201) {
                LOGGER.info("Success");
              } else {
                // Is this exception propagated to the caller?
                throw new RuntimeException("Very bad unrecoverable state");
              }
}
```

Of cause this could be optimized a bit more if you find a more generalized solution to merge `postDataToMicroserviceA()` and `logErrorResponse()`, since basically they do the same...